# measure temperature in a solenoid without sensot

Tags: solenoid, coil

is possible to meassure the temperature change in solenoid , without using a sensor?

I know the resistance will change with temperature, but are other parameters affected also ? will my current waveform change ??

Comment: The time constant is L/R so it will change with resistance and thus temperature, but the time to get to a given current (and thus field strength) will hardly change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can estimate the change in temperature of the copper windings of a solenoid, by measuring their resistance. The tempco of resistance for copper is about +10% for every 25C rise. You can get accurate values from a resource like Kaye and Laby online, [here](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_6/2_6_1.html).

If your driving source is sensitive to the resistance, then yes, your waveform will change slightly. If it is a high output impedance current source, then no, the waveform will not change with changes in resistance.

Other parameters like the expansion due to temperature affecting the self inductance or capacitance will be pretty negligible, unless you make very sensitive measurements.